# How to set duplicates at EList

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-emf, eclipse-emf-ecore, emf

I have been trying to set duplicates,Strings,at EList.

The issue that the following method bans to add duplicates:

```
elist.set(index, value);
```

I have been searching on a way that fixes that and I have found that I need to disable Uniqueness but this would may affect the rest of framework.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable the uniqueness setting has been how I have handled this. What are the effects to the rest of the framework?

Comment: Thanks GLNN for your assistance :)